# How to Center a text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I am making my app and I want to center a piece of text in Android Studio.

This is the code that I am currently using.

```
<activity
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:label="Login to Notely"
        android:name=".ActivityLogin"/>
```

All I want to do is to center the 'Login to Notely' text which will be there at the top of the app.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `<TextView>`

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` is the subelement of `Application` and represents an `activity` that must be defined in the `AndroidManifest. xml` file. It has many attributes such as label, name, theme, launchMode etc. `android:label` represents a label i.e. displayed on the screen.
It performs some other tasks also:

- It is responsible to protect the `application` to access any protected parts by providing the permissions.
- It also declares the android `API` that the application is going to use.
- It lists the instrumentation classes. The instrumentation classes provide profiling and other pieces of information. These pieces of information are removed just before the application is published etc.

One thing is clear that `<activity>` has nothing to do with organizing your text.

Now to center your `activity` text, you have to first define a `ViewGroup`(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstrainLayout etc) inside `XML` file. In this example, I am using `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello World"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful but where should I put this code into?

And one more thing. Instead of the text, can you place an image? It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: To place an image you have to replace <TextView> with <ImageView>, for more detail please visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView. Secondly, if answer was helpful then please mark it accepted.